# Is it possible to execute a command on the local computer in meterpreter?

Tags: metasploit

While running meterpreter handler, is it possible to execute a command on the local computer?

That wasn't mentioned in the output of `help` command. I also tried `!ls` and to no avail.

Is it possible then?

Answer (score 9):

http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Meterpreter_Basics#execute

> The 'execute' command runs a command on the target

http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Meterpreter_Basics#shell

> The 'shell' command will present you with a standard shell on the
>   target system.

If you want to run the command on the attacker host press Ctrl+Z to background the Meterpreter shell, and issue your command in the Metasploit shell. You can return to Meterpreter with the `session` command.

Comment: this is correct. But how to automate that? I have create a file: `msfconsole -r file.rb` but commands are run only within the `msfconsole` application. How to automate the shell commands? Or how to automate the `execute -f cmd.exe -i -H` IN the meterpreter?

Comment: @Sebastian I think this post will answer your question: http://hexesec.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/scripting-post-exploitation/

Answer (score 0):

For Windows: In meterpreter run the following to execute a batch command creating a file:

```
execute -H -k -f cmd -a "/c touch file.txt"
```

Where:

```
-f: command to execute (File in %PATH%)
-c: Arguments to the command, expects a string
-H: Hidden
-k: in pwd
/c: exeCute next string
```

Sources:

- [Meterpreter execute](https://www.offsec.com/metasploit-unleashed/meterpreter-basics/#execute)
- [Windows cmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd)

Comment: This just repeats part of the other answer. Did you intend to have a unique take on the question?